# Genymotion: virtual device

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, genymotion

I'm trying to run a Samsung S5 as virtual device in Genymotion. (For Hearthstone card back promotion)

I've enabled Virtual Technology in the BIOS, but the program is still not able to run the device.

I've made a video showing the problem [here](https://vid.me/RceF)

The original guide is [here](https://netdeck.n4ru.it/free-galaxy-gifts-cardback-and-3-packs/) (I'm stuck at point 5)

Thanks in advance. Please explain it as simple as possible, I'm a novice at IT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried (from Common Errors,  https://netdeck.n4ru.it/free-galaxy-gifts-cardback-and-3-packs/):

> This is slightly tricky to fix. You need to reboot and go into your
>   computer BIOS and enable Virtualization Technology, then start Windows
>   and Genymotion but do not launch the virtual device yet. You need to
>   open the device settings from within Genymotion’s main window (NOT the
>   Android settings after launching the phone). Set the number of CPUs to
>   2, and set the memory to 4,000 (3,000 or 2,000 if you don’t have
>   enough RAM). Then launch the device again.

Comment: Hello Danielson. Yes I have, that is exactly what I tried to show you in the video. Didn't work, unless I've done something wrong? :(

Comment: Are you able to run something else on the VirtualBox? Like a x64 linux? Just to test the virtualization... I'm unsure whether you need the x64... Or the x32 instead... Parhaps it has to do with not enough memory?

Comment: Doesn't seem like I can run that either: Maybe that's the problem? "Cannot acces the Kernel driver! Make sure the kernel module has been loaded succesfully"

Comment: can you try an other version of VBox? You do have an x64 OS?

Comment: Check this https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4140 it might be a VBox bug, perhaps the fix can help you... (btw, this has become a non-SO question ;-) )

Comment: Okay neither OS or windows could run. Same error code. I give up... But thanks for the help :)